# Are objects of type nullptr_t ever needed?

Tags: c++, c++11, nullptr

Quoting C++11: (18.2/9)

> `nullptr_t` is defined as follows:
>
> ```
> namespace std { typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t; }
> ```
>
> The type for
>   which `nullptr_t` is a synonym has the characteristics described in
>   3.9.1 and 4.10. [ Note: Although `nullptr`’s address cannot be taken, **the address of another `nullptr_t` object** that is an lvalue can be taken. —end note ]

Do we ever need objects of type `nullptr_t` (other than `nullptr`)?

Comment: Did you see the example on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t)?

Comment: did you ever have to use `NULL` ? the answer is basically the same

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 `NULL` is similar to `nullptr`, they are values. `nullptr_t` is a type. I think OP is asking if it's ever useful to instantiate a new object of type `nullptr_t` other than `nullptr`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux oh I missed the "other than `nullptr`". Suddenly it perfectly makes sense. Sorry, should have read more carefully.

Comment: I don't think there could be useful use of explicitly declare an object of type `nullptr_t`.

Answer (score 7):

`nullptr` is a prvalue, so you cannot take its address.  (It is not an object.)  The note is referring to cases like this:

```
nullptr_t n;
```

Then, `n` is an ordinary object of type `nullptr_t` so you can take its address.  This doesn’t seem to be useful whatsoever, but in generic code this feature may come in somehow.

Answer (score 7):

It's useful in this instance, which is good enough for me:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int bonus(int){return std::numeric_limits<int>::max();}
int bonus(std::nullptr_t){return 0;}

int main()
{
    std::nullptr_t bar;
    std::cout << bonus(0) << "\n";
    std::cout << bonus(nullptr) << "\n";
    std::cout << bonus(bar) << "\n";
}
```

C++ is a general purpose language and it would be annoying if the type associated with `nullptr` was not part of the overload resolution system.

Comment: What do you mean? Mu question is about objects, not about the type associated with nullptr...

Comment: @embedc: `bar`is an object. A more elaborate example would be something based on a `std::variant<std::nullptr_t, int>`.

Comment: But why bar is useful in your example? Why did you create it?